# Convert ls Output Into an Array

Tags: arrays, bash, ls

I want to put the output of an ls into an array so I can loop through it and eventually use a entry the user will specify.

What I did is the following

```
SETUPS="$(ls)"
IFS=$' ' read -rd '' setup <<<"$SETUPS"
```

when I run `echo $setup[0]` it will already show me all the files that are present
while I should be able to run `echo $setup[0]` and only get the first entry.

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

I already tried `SETUPS="$(ls -1)"` to seperate it with `IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' setup <<<"$SETUPS"` but that didn't work either.

Right now I'm looping through it like this

```
n=0
for i in `echo ${setup} | tr "," " "` 
   do
   n=$((n+1))
   echo $n". $i"
done
```

which works to echo every entry with a number in front of it but I can't possibly select an entry out of there since every value seems to be stored as 1 value

Comment: @Inian I want to show the user the file names

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to get all the files in this directory in an array you can use globbing:

```
files=(*)
printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}"
```

will store all the files matched by the glob in the array `files` and then you can print them with `printf` if you so desire, or do whatever else you want with looping over the array.

```
n=0
for current in "${files[@]}"; do
    n=((n+1))
    printf '%s %s\n' "$n" "$current"
done
```

You don't even need to store it in an array in the middle if you don't need it for some other purpose:

```
for current in *; do
```

works just fine

Answer (score 2):

See, why [not parse output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), but rather use a proper `while` loop with [process-substitution (<()).](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst)

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
    printf "%s\n" "${file#*/}" 
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -print0)
```

(or) if you are interested in storing the folder contents in an array

```
fileContents=()
while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
    fileContents+=("${file#*/}") 
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -print0)

printf "%s\n" "${fileContents[@]}"
```

Comment: this will display it as `./example`
I need it to be `example` and the first one is an empty entry

Comment: it did remove the ./ characters.
when printing it will show:

`<null>`
`.`
`.git`
`config`

so the first one is a blank line. then the hidden values are shown then the first file I actually want to show is being shown

Comment: Null meaning blank line. nothing there just a entry in the array that is completely empty